# Filtering bounded data in Dataflow based on timestamp

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

In my dataflow pipeline, I'll have two `PCollections<TableRow>` that have been read from BigQuery tables. I plan to merge those two PCollections into one `PCollection` with with a [`flatten`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/multiple-pcollections#applying-a-flatten-transform).

Since BigQuery is append only, the goal is to write truncate the second table in BigQuery with the a new `PCollection`.

I've read through the documentation and it's the middle steps I'm confused about. With my new `PCollection` the plan is to use a `Comparator DoFn` to look at the max last update date and returning the given row. **I'm unsure if I should be using a filter transform or if I should be doing a Group by key and then using a filter?**

All `PCollection<TableRow>`s will contain the same values: IE: string, integer and timestamp. When it comes to key value pairs, most of the documentation on cloud dataflow includes just simple strings. **Is it possible to have a key value pair that is the entire row of the `PCollection<TableRow>`?**

The rows would look similar to:

```
customerID, customerName, lastUpdateDate
0001, customerOne, 2016-06-01 00:00:00
0001, customerOne, 2016-06-11 00:00:00
```

In the example above, I would want to filter the PCollection to just return the second row to a PCollection that would be written to BigQuery. **Also, is it possible to apply these `Pardo`'s on the third PCollection without creating a fourth?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a few questions. I have tried to answer them in isolation, but I may have misunderstood the whole scenario. If you provided some example code, it might help to clarify.

> With my new PCollection the plan is to use a Comparator DoFn to look at the max last update date and returning the given row. I'm unsure if I should be using a filter transform or if I should be doing a Group by key and then using a filter?

Based on your description, it seems that you want to take a `PCollection` of elements and for each `customerID` (the key) find the most recent update to that customer's record. You can use the provided transforms to accomplish this via `Top.largestPerKey(1, timestampComparator)` where you set up your `timestampComparator` to look only at the timestamp.

> Is it possible to have a key value pair that is the entire row of the PCollection?

A `KV<K, V>` can have any type for the key (`K`) and value (`V`). If you want to group by key, then the coder for the keys needs to be deterministic. `TableRowJsonCoder` is not deterministic, because it may contain arbitrary objects. But it sounds like you want to have the `customerID` for the key and the entire `TableRow` for the value.

> is it possible to apply these Pardo's on the third PCollection without creating a fourth?

When you apply a `PTransform` to a `PCollection`, it results in a new `PCollection`. There is no way around that, and you don't need to try to minimize the number of `PCollections` in your pipeline.

A `PCollection` is a conceptual object; it does not have intrinsic cost. Your pipeline is going to be heavily optimized so that many intermediate `PCollections` - especially those in a sequence of `ParDo` transforms - will never be materialized anyhow.